# CSS - targetting for Window Chrome ONLY

Tags: javascript, css, windows, google-chrome

I am testing on both Mac and Windows.  Chrome in Mac looks as expected, but Chrome in Windows doesn't.  I have a CSS selector below for Chrome, but it happens in both Mac and Windows.

I wonder if there is a selector/setting for Windows Chrome only.  Please give me a hand.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ 
    .class {...}
}
```

Comment: It's not a "hack". What are you suggesting you're hacking?

Comment: @ProEvilz This is a common CSS term, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_hack — but yes, this question needs to specify _what_ is going on.

Comment: For example I want to get text is red in in Mac Chrome, but text will be green in Window Chrome.  Is that possible?

Comment: If you want straightforward way, it is not possible, there is no such a selector like that, the only solution that I can think about is javascript to read the OS and add a specific class, and make that special style inside that class for chrome.

Comment: Hi Al-Mothafar, Yes, it sounds right!  Can you please have an example?